# Compare dates with different different pattern

Tags: java, compare, date-format

Simplest way to compare two dates, if am having same pattern.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date1 = sdf.parse("2009-12-31");
        Date date2 = sdf.parse("2010-01-31");

        System.out.println(sdf.format(date1));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date2));

        if(date1.after(date2)){
            System.out.println("Date1 is after Date2");
        }

        if(date1.before(date2)){
            System.out.println("Date1 is before Date2");
        }

        if(date1.equals(date2)){
            System.out.println("Date1 is equal Date2");
        }
```

Want to compare 2 dates having different different pattern.

for eg.

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date1 = sdf.parse("2009-12-31");
 SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date2 = sdf2.parse("12/12/2012");
```

How can i do the same

Comment: You've got `date1` & `date2` - just compare them as before. That's it!

Comment: I believe if you already have two valid instances of date then before, equals, after will work. It doesn depend on how these instances have been constructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the dates in the same way. `SimpleDateFormat` is simply a method of printing the dates in (or parsing them from) different formats. Java understands them and can can compare them as dates no matter how you have them formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Even after parsing the 2 different dates of 2 different formats, the output of `parse()` method is going to be a standard `java.util.Date` object in both the cases. So you can compare them as usual.

The format from which they were parsed doesn't matter, because at the end you've 2 `java.util.Date` objects, in both the cases, and comparing them is the same, in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

You replaced sdf with sdf2

Change to this code and it will work:

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date date2 = sdf2.parse("12/12/2012");
```

You used the wrong reference sdf instead of sdf2